# How to plot colors on CIE 1931 Color Space in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, scatter-plot, color-space

I'm trying to plot few color values (co-ordinates) on the already plotted CIE 1931 color space. I've derived the XYZ color values which I want to plot, denoted as `[X, Y, Z]`-

`[50, 57, 10]`
`[36, 43, 15]`
`[28, 36, 8]`
`[25, 32, 14]`

I using this function which plots the entire CIE color space - 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40640-computational-colour-science-using-matlab-2e/content//cieplot.m

```
 cieplot();
 hold on
 x=[0.42 0.58]
 y=[0.48 0.45];
 scatter(x,y);
 hold off
```

I've used the below two formulas for calculating the `x` and `y` values used in the above code to plot 2 colors as an example and it generates the figure/graph shown. One of the 2 colors goes outside the desired color spectrum. I'm confused as to how to plot `z` coordinate which can be calculated as `z=1-x-y` on the shown CIE color space, so that all the colors fit within the spectrum.

[image: Formula to calculate x]

[image: Formula to calculate y]

[image: Generated Plot/Figure]

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. The chromacity diagram is `x vs. y`. How exactly do what to incorporate the `z` value and why? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to simply plot colors defined by `[X,Y,Z]` on a CIE 1931 Color Space. A color cannot be represented by only `x` and `y`. I'm trying to figure how colors are plotted in such color space using matlab. Refer o this for further details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space

Comment: @horchler I have a list of few colors which I want to correlate depending on their plot in the CIE color space i.e. if their are n colors `[c1, c2, c3 ... cn]` how are the connected (if they increase linearly, circularly in the graph).

Comment: The colors can be represented by `x` and `y`, hence why this is called a [chromaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity) diagram (a.k.a. color space). It looks like you're trying to plot the three-dimensional space of color and luminance (where `Y` is luminance for CIE 1931).

Comment: But why is the color I plotted going out of the color spectrum when I used their `x` and `y` value? Because `[50, 57, 10]` `[36, 43, 15]` are simply shades of green.

Comment: Using `rgb2xyz`, I don't see how you get those particular xy values. Please edit you question to show your full runnable code with how you converted from RGB triplets to XYZ triplets to xyY triplets.

Comment: @horchler How can one build one of the chromaticity diagrams from scratch? I'm trying to understand how to take either srgb or xyz values and map them to the two dimensional space.

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample I'd start by looking at the code for [this MathWorks FileExchange contribution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40640-computational-colour-science-using-matlab-2e).

Comment: I've been looking at `cieplot()` but I'm not sure it's correct. It doesn't translate from xyY to XYZ before translating to rgb. Can you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278029/horchler), the mistake was in my color conversion (RGB to XYZ to xyY) which I had done external to MATLAB. On correcting the error, the following code produced the desired result.

```
cieplot();
hold on
x=[0.42 0.38 0.388 0.352 0.344 0.281]
y=[0.48 0.45 0.5 0.45 0.452 0.352];
scatter(x,y,10,'filled');
i=1;
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
strValues = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(a(:),'(%d)')));
text(x,y,strValues,'VerticalAlignment','bottom');
hold off
```

The graph shows the six colors plotted in CIE 1931 color space as per their `x` and `y` values.
[image: The resultant graph]

Comment: I thought you wanted a three-dimensional plot? Where is Y in your code?